# showing a convex function s subharmonic

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Given a $C^2$ convex function $f$ and $u$ a harmonic function in an open subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$, how  can I show that $f(u)$ is sub-harmonic?

Comment: How $u$ is important in your question? Are you just asking that $C^2$ convex function is subharmonic?

Comment: @Ilya, thank you. I meant $f(u)$. I want to show $-\Delta f(u) \leq 0$.

Comment: I hope, you meant $-\Delta f\leq 0$

Comment: use Jensen's inequality to show averages over balls smaller than value at center, (or bigger, whichever is right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also simply compute derivatives since everything is differentiable enough: 
$$
(f(u))_x = f'\cdot u_x\Rightarrow (f(u))_{xx} = f'' u_x^2+f'u_{xx}
$$
and clearly, $(f(u))_{yy} = f'' u_y^2+f' u_{yy}$. As a result,
$$
\Delta f(u) = f'' (u_x^2+u_y^2)\geq 0
$$
since $f$ is a convex $C^2$ function.

Comment: just that simple! Thanks very much.